# How to append new values to an already existing value in a parse database?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have a table in parse.com database called as test. I have a column called phone number in it. So i successfully inserted a value in the column (ex. 123456789) now i want to append another value in the same field. (Ex. 123456789,987654321) How do I do that ? I am using Parse and Xcode together. The language which I am using is swift.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's Swift, but you can do it like this in Objective-c, (I'm sure it's close to the swift version):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"className"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

  if (object) {

 // let's update your phone number
    NSString *numbers = @"123";
    NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",object[@"telNumber"], numbers]
    object[@"telNumber"] = newStr;
    [object saveInBackground];
}

}];
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try if out

Comment: @RizwanAhmed Be sure you are updating the same object you queried, every Parse object is like a dictionary so you can easily modify the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add another column or do you want to change the current value in the column phone number?

To add another column you can create a new colmn in parse or you create it programatically:

```
var stream = PFObject(className: "test")
stream["phoneNumber"] = "123"
stream["anotherValue"] = "abc"

func saveInBackgroundWithBlock(stream: PFObject) {
    stream.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        var withStatus = "succ"

        if !succeeded {
            withStatus = "not succ"
        }
        print("Upload: \(withStatus)")
    }

}
```

If you want to edit the current value you have to edit it in the following way:

```
let phoneNumber = "345"
stream.setValue(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        user?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            var withStatus = "succ Change"

            if !succeeded {
                withStatus = "not SuccChange"
            }
            print("Upload: \(withStatus)")
        }
```

If I answered or understood your question wrong, please feel free to correct me. Regards, Alex

Comment: No actually, I want to add a value to an existing field with an existing value. The old value must also be there after adding the new value to the field :)

Comment: Just to got you right: You have e.g. the old value "123" in your phone number table. You want to add e.g. "456" maybe after your old value -> Just get your current value (stream["phoneNumber"] as? String) - save this in an temp var and then just use my 2nd code snipped and work with temp variables....

Comment: Okay I will try it and get back to you :-)

Comment: No this doesn't actually work. Is there any way that would append the values without retrieving the old values from the parse table ? something like comma seperated values (CSV) ?